# jbooss with RUNASIS option

Tags: jboss

I am starting the jboss_3.2.7 with the linux user jbs using jboss with RUNASIS option, but it is not working while the entire system[linux] restart. Which is starting the jboss as root user.

I added the jboss service in chkconfig option of linux for starting the jboss on linux restart.

Answer (score 0):

In the jboss service file (/etc/init.d) modified the user to RUNASIS
define the user under which jboss will run, or use RUNASIS to run as the current user

JBOSSUS=${JBOSSUS:-"RUNASIS"}

Comment: Which is working fine when starting the jboss as the linux logging user is jbs. But on Linux(OS) restart it is starting as root.

Answer (score 0):

You are using quite old JBoss version and I personally never see it. But I think it should be very similar to newer ones.

Please try to put your user after when defining these variable:

```
JBOSSUS=jbs
```

The other solution is to setting these variable before executing running script:

```
export JBOSSUS=jbs; /etc/init.d/jboss start
```

**Update**

I have just downloaded JBoss 3.2.7 and I checked the `jboss_init_redhat.sh` script (I hope you use these one as a templete for your starting script).

In the file `jboss_init_redhat.sh` you can find such lines:

```
#define the user under which jboss will run, or use RUNASIS 
#to run as the current user
JBOSSUS=${JBOSSUS:-"jboss"}
```

These line defines the new user name. It checks if the variable `JBOSSUS` is set up and if not is uses `jboss` user as default name.

The second interesting part of these script:

```
if [ "$JBOSSUS" = "RUNASIS" ]; then
  SUBIT=""
else
  SUBIT="su - $JBOSSUS -c "
fi
```

You should know one thing: when you run automatically any script from init scripts it is always run as a `root` user. Thats why in the script should be command which change the effective user to someone else. And here you have these part of the script.

It first checked if your username is `RUNASIS` and if it is **yes** - do nothing. In another case it run JBoss as a another user by using `su` command.

In your case it should be sufficient to change `JBOSSUS` variable definition to something like that:

JBOSSUS=jbs

After that you can start these script as a `root` user and it should run JVM with JBoss with `jbs` user.

Comment: If I use this which will Prompt for jbs(user) password,  To avoid this I gone for RUNASIS option and it is working fine. The RUNASIS will takes the logged in user.

Comment: But On os reboot jboss is starting with root user .

Comment: I don't have these JBoss installation file. Could you provide all init script? It will be much easer to check waht is going on the script.